# Feel the "need for speed" Using reduce(into:_:) to count elements in enclosing array of sets of triplet elements

Tags: swift, block, reduce, counting

**given this example array of triplets**, real arrays would be very large data sets,  hence the "need for speed":

```
let usedIndicies2 = [
    [0, 1, 2]
    [2, 1, 3],
    [1, 4, 3],
    [3, 4, 5],
    [6, 7, 8],
    [8, 7, 9],
    [7, 10, 9],
    [9, 10, 11],
    [12, 2, 13],
    [13, 2, 14],
    [2, 3, 14],
    [14, 3, 15],
    [3, 5, 15],
    [15, 5, 16],
    [5, 17, 16],
    [16, 17, 18],
    [19, 8, 20],
    [20, 8, 21],
    [8, 9, 21],
    [21, 9, 22],
    [9, 11, 22],
    [22, 11, 23],
    [11, 24, 23],
    [23, 24, 25],
    [13, 14, 26],
    [26, 14, 27],
    [14, 15, 27],
    [27, 15, 28],
    [15, 16, 28],
    [28, 16, 29],
    [16, 18, 29],
    [29, 18, 30],
    [18, 20, 30],
    [30, 20, 31],
    [20, 21, 31],
    [31, 21, 32],
    [21, 22, 32],
    [32, 22, 33],
    [22, 23, 33],
    [33, 23, 34],
    [26, 27, 35],
    [35, 27, 36],
    [27, 28, 36],
    [36, 28, 37],
    [28, 29, 37],
    [37, 29, 38],
    [29, 30, 38],
    [38, 30, 39],
    [30, 31, 39],
    [39, 31, 40],
    [31, 32, 40],
    [40, 32, 41],
    [32, 33, 41],
    [41, 33, 42],
    [33, 34, 42],
    [42, 34, 43],
    [44, 35, 45],
    [45, 35, 46],
    [35, 36, 46],
    [46, 36, 47],
    [36, 37, 47],
    [47, 37, 48],
    [37, 38, 48],
    [48, 38, 49],
    [38, 39, 49],
    [49, 39, 50],
    [39, 40, 50],
    [50, 40, 51],
    [40, 41, 51],
    [51, 41, 52],
    [41, 42, 52],
    [52, 42, 53],
    [42, 43, 53],
    [53, 43, 54],
    [43, 55, 54],
    [54, 55, 56],
]
```

**Using swift**,  find the counts of each element of this type of array, while preserving the triplets,  so the output would look like this:

```
let keyValuePairs =[
  [[0: 1], [1: 3], [2: 5]],
  [[2: 5], [1: 3], [3: 6]],
  [[1: 3], [4: 2], [3: 6]],
  [[3: 6], [4: 2], [5: 4]],
  [[6: 1], [7: 3], [8: 5]],
  [[8: 5], [7: 3], [9: 6]],
  [[7: 3], [10: 2], [9: 6]],
  [[9: 6], [10: 2], [11: 4]],
  // etc. ...
]
```

I am only *suggesting* "reduce(into" as it feels like it is possible, but it maybe something else entirely that is better/faster/stronger.

(*does not have to preserve the order of the triplet sets*,  **but must preserver the order of elements inside the triplet**:  for instance the first and second one needs to stay [[0:x], [1:x], [2:x]], [[2:x], [1:x], [3:x]],   or as an example the order could [[2:x], [1:x], [3:x]], [[0:x], [1:x], [2:x]] instead.

**So far I've been able to produce the correct organization** using this code below,  it feels like this could be solved with reduce(into:_:)  but I couldn't correctly "count" the elements..  i've left the code in that doesn't count correctly,  obviously because it is intialized each time, but wanted to show what I had so far:

```
let keyValuePairs = usedIndicies2.reduce(into: [[[UInt32:Int]]]()) { (array, entry) in

    var dict0:[UInt32:Int] = [UInt32:Int]()
    var dict1:[UInt32:Int] = [UInt32:Int]()
    var dict2:[UInt32:Int] = [UInt32:Int]()

    dict0[entry[0], default: 0] += 1
    dict1[entry[1], default: 0] += 1
    dict2[entry[2], default: 0] += 1

    var array012:[[UInt32:Int]] = [[UInt32:Int]]()

    array012.append(dict0)
    array012.append(dict1)
    array012.append(dict2)

    array.append(array012)
}

print("keyValuePairs:",keyValuePairs)
```

**the output of this partially working code looks like this**:

```
let keyValuePairs** = [
    [[0: 1], [1: 1], [2: 1]],
    [[2: 1], [1: 1], [3: 1]],
    [[1: 1], [4: 1], [3: 1]],
    [[3: 1], [4: 1], [5: 1]],
    [[6: 1], [7: 1], [8: 1]],
    [[8: 1], [7: 1], [9: 1]],
    [[7: 1], [10: 1], [9: 1]],
    [[9: 1], [10: 1], [11: 1]],
    // etc...
]
```

**would greatly appreciate your insights**

Comment: Seems pretty simple actually. First, flatten the array and just make an ordinary histogram (count) for all values (that's a one-liner). Then go back to the original array and map it into the array of pairs.

Comment: I would like to do it within one block, as that seems like what reduce can do the best,  the histogram would indeed be easy,  but preserving the triplet order has been difficult in one block.

Comment: I don't really know what "in one block" means.

Comment: or if you wish, as few loops/functions/branches as possible,  it feels like the reduce(into: can do this with very few "extra" interventions,  I of course could be wrong.

Comment: Shrug. I've explained how to perform the task you described. My algorithm seems elegant and simple to me, but hey, you're the questioner, you get to decide whether you like my explanation or not. Either way, my work is done.

Comment: I added the comment before seeing the answer appear...  I'll look over your algorithm,  thanks.

Comment: @hokkuk follow up on his answer `let output = original.map{ array in array.map {[$0:histo[$0]!]}}`

Comment: @LeoDabus Yeah, the point of my tweak is that I fail to see the value of a dictionary with just one entry. Just a lot of overhead for no purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two steps:

1. Flatten the array and just make an ordinary histogram (count) for all values (that's a one-liner).
2. Now go back to the original array and map it into the array of pairs.

To demonstrate, I'll just operate on the opening piece of your data just to prove it works. I've given my own interpretation of the notion of a key value pair (I've used a tuple with labels), but feel free to patch that up as desired.

```
let original = [[0, 1, 2], [2, 1, 3], [1, 4, 3], [3, 4, 5]]
// step 1
var histo = [Int:Int]()
original.flatMap {$0}.forEach {histo[$0, default:0] += 1}
// step 2
let output = original.map {array in array.map {i in (item:i, count:histo[i]!)}}
```

Result:

```
[[(item: 0, count: 1), (item: 1, count: 3), (item: 2, count: 2)], 
 [(item: 2, count: 2), (item: 1, count: 3), (item: 3, count: 3)], 
 [(item: 1, count: 3), (item: 4, count: 2), (item: 3, count: 3)], 
 [(item: 3, count: 3), (item: 4, count: 2), (item: 5, count: 1)]]
```

And that is correct.

Comment: Thanks for this two step process,  and it may indeed not be possible to do in a single reduce(into: block.   It feels like it could be possible,  so I'll wait and see if someone can show a reduce(into: function (or what ever function) that speed wise would be better,   as I would be using this on massive sets of data.  I'll add the "need for speed" to my question title of "reduce(into"  :)

Comment: Sure, fair enough. Every time I have a left curly brace in the above code, that's a loop. But please note that I do not see how you reduce the number of loops, because by the time you start dealing things out, you _must_ know the histogram count already. If you didn't, you would have to go back each time you encounter an already used element and change the count in all mentions of that element that have already been dealt out, which is exponential. Therefore I think my way _is_ the fast way and your `reduce(into:)` spec is a red herring (also known as an x-y problem).